# Unable to generate a POST endpoint in Micronaut from OpenAPI

Tags: micronaut, openapi-generator

I am trying to use openapi-generator with Micronaut but the build fails with:

```
warning: Error:
  Cannot invoke "String.equals(Object)" because the return value of "io.swagger.v3.oas.models.parameters.Parameter.getIn()" is null
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.equals(Object)" because the return value of "io.swagger.v3.oas.models.parameters.Parameter.getIn()" is null
    at io.micronaut.openapi.visitor.SchemaUtils.mergeOperations(SchemaUtils.java:324)
    at io.micronaut.openapi.visitor.OpenApiApplicationVisitor.mergeMicronautEndpointInfos(OpenApiApplicationVisitor.java:734)
    at io.micronaut.openapi.visitor.OpenApiApplicationVisitor.finish(OpenApiApplicationVisitor.java:504)
    at io.micronaut.annotation.processing.TypeElementVisitorProcessor.process(TypeElementVisitorProcessor.java:289)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.DelegatingProcessor.process(DelegatingProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.DynamicProcessor.process(DynamicProcessor.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.DelegatingProcessor.process(DelegatingProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.TimeTrackingProcessor.access$401(TimeTrackingProcessor.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.TimeTrackingProcessor$5.create(TimeTrackingProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.TimeTrackingProcessor$5.create(TimeTrackingProcessor.java:96)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.TimeTrackingProcessor.track(TimeTrackingProcessor.java:117)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.TimeTrackingProcessor.process(TimeTrackingProcessor.java:96)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1023)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:939)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1267)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1382)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1234)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:916)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.invocationHelper(JavacTaskImpl.java:152)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.IncrementalCompileTask.call(IncrementalCompileTask.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.call(AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ResourceCleaningCompilationTask.call(ResourceCleaningCompilationTask.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:98)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ModuleApplicationNameWritingCompiler.execute(ModuleApplicationNameWritingCompiler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ModuleApplicationNameWritingCompiler.execute(ModuleApplicationNameWritingCompiler.java:36)
    at org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.DefaultToolchainJavaCompiler.execute(DefaultToolchainJavaCompiler.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.lambda$createToolchainCompiler$3(JavaCompile.java:202)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompiler.execute(CleaningJavaCompiler.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilerFactory.lambda$createRebuildAllCompiler$0(IncrementalCompilerFactory.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.SelectiveCompiler.execute(SelectiveCompiler.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.SelectiveCompiler.execute(SelectiveCompiler.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.execute(IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.execute(IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler$1.call(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler$1.call(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.execute(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:220)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performIncrementalCompilation(JavaCompile.java:161)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:146)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:125)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.execute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:233)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:216)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:199)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:105)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:28)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.executeDelegateBroadcastingChanges(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:72)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:179)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:77)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNonEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:177)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:86)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:23)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.lambda$execute$2(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:66)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.execute(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.execute(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:293)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:21)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:146)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:331)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.lambda$execute$0(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationRef.with(CurrentBuildOperationRef.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
error: Error finalizing type visitor [io.micronaut.openapi.visitor.OpenApiApplicationVisitor@7a428686]: Cannot invoke "String.equals(Object)" because the return value of "io.swagger.v3.oas.models.parameters.Parameter.getIn()" is null
Note: Creating bean classes for 3 type elements
Note: Writing OpenAPI file to destination: /Users/jjrz/dev/ninja2/build/classes/java/main/META-INF/swagger/ninja2-0.0.yml
Note: Writing OpenAPI views to destination: /Users/jjrz/dev/ninja2/build/classes/java/main/META-INF/swagger/views
1 error
1 warning

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Here is my OpenAPI spec:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Ninja
tags:
  - name: rentals
paths:
  /rentals:
    post:
      tags:
        - rentals
      operationId: create
      requestBody:
        content:
          "application/json":
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/RentalInfo"
      responses:
        "201":
          description: Created
          content:
            "application/json":
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/RentalInfo"
        "400":
          description: Bad Request
components:
  schemas:
    RentalInfo:
      type: object
      properties:
        uuid: { type: string }
        name: { type: string }
      required: [ "uuid", "name" ]
```

My API implementation:

```java
@Controller
class Rentals implements RentalsApi {

    @Override
    public HttpResponse<RentalInfo> create(final RentalInfo rentalInfo) {
        return HttpResponse.created(rentalInfo);
    }
}
```

And my Gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id("groovy") 
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "8.1.1"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "4.0.4"
    id("io.micronaut.aot") version "4.0.4"
    id("io.micronaut.openapi") version "4.0.4"
}

version = "0.1"
group = "dev.jjrz"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation")
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.openapi:micronaut-openapi")
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.serde:micronaut-serde-processor")
    implementation("io.micronaut.security:micronaut-security")
    implementation("io.micronaut.serde:micronaut-serde-jackson")
    implementation("io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations")
    compileOnly("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    testImplementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
}


application {
    mainClass.set("dev.jjrz.ninja2.Application")
}
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("17")
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("17")
}

graalvmNative.toolchainDetection = false
micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("spock2")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("dev.jjrz.*")
    }
    aot {
        optimizeServiceLoading = false
        convertYamlToJava = false
        precomputeOperations = true
        cacheEnvironment = true
        optimizeClassLoading = true
        deduceEnvironment = true
        optimizeNetty = true
    }
    openapi {
        server(file("src/main/resources/ninja2-api.yml")) {
            apiPackageName = "dev.jjrz.ninja2.api"
            modelPackageName = "dev.jjrz.ninja2.model"
            useReactive = false
            useAuth = true
        }
    }
}
```

The build passes if I remove the request body. It also passes if the Java class is not annotated with `@Controller` but I believe it is necessary to make it work.

Has anyone been able to make a POST request work with Micronaut and the generator?

Comment: Hi, please share the openapi-generator config which you used to create your micronaut client.

Comment: I don't have an openapi-generator config file. It is not mentioned in the Micronaut guide: https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-openapi-generator-server-gradle-java.html

Comment: Ah, I assumed you used [OpenAPI Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/). But apparently you used the Micronaut Maven Plugin instead. Then I hope someone with more knowledge about the latter can help you. :)